# Post complex json using RestKit in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, arrays, post, restkit

I'm having an issue posting json by using RestKit, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.
The request json sample is:

```
{
  "Name": "sample string 1", 
  "Interests": {
    "Array": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
}
```

My code:

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"Name": @"Name"}];

    RKObjectMapping *interestsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];

    RKObjectMapping *interestIDMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[KLInterest class]];
    [interestIDMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"InterestID"]];

    [interestsMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Array" toKeyPath:@"Array" withMapping:interestIDMapping]];


    [requestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Interests" toKeyPath:@"Interests" withMapping:interestsMapping]];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[NSMutableDictionary class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
    [self.objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];


    NSDictionary *data = [business toDictionary];

    [self sendRequest:@"api/Business/Create" Method:@"POST" Data:data withCallback:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary response, NSError error) {
        callback(success, response, error);
    }];
```

KLInterestID.h

```
@interface KLInterestID : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *InterestID;
@end
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. I'm not familiar with the `relationshipMappingFromKeyPath`  and `attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil` functions. 
I'm not sure how to send `int` array.
Thanks

Comment: So you aren't using core data and your objects aren't actually nested (the object you want to create the JSON from)?